# What function should i use for this?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

if L4 is "A" S4 value must more than T4 = 1.5(1.5 Come from value in O4)
If its true N4 will show text 2(2 come from value in M4) If its false its will show “0”

If L4 is "B" S4 value must not less than T4 = 1.5(1.5 Come from value in O4)
If its true N4 will show text 2(2 come from value in M4) If its false its will show “0”

Updated !!
Now i have convert the underline text to "A" And not Underline to "B"

yes now same question

Comment: As far as I know you can not test in a formula if something is underlined or not.  You would need to write a UDF in vba to do that.  And SO is not a code for me site.

Comment: Why are you basing it off of formatting anyway? Data rules should come from data, not formatting.  A better question might be determining why the values in column L are underlined, and then test for that.

Comment: thanks you i'm new for this

Comment: how about if i convert text that Underline To A and Not underline To B so will its work?

Comment: "S4 value must more than T4 = 1.5" - this seems mis-typed

Comment: You should use `IF()` for this.

Comment: I am not sure how to interpret what you want but my guess is `=IF(L4="A",IF(S4>T4,M4,0),IF(L4="B",IF(NOT(S4<T4),M4,0),"Must be A or B"))`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I follow 100% but I have this:

`=IF(AND(L4="A",S4>T4),M4,IF(AND(L4="B",S4<T4),M4,0))`

It doesn't touch O4, but sounds like T4 pulls it's value from there anyway.